# Compare current password before doing a password reset -- Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

Is there any way to compare a plain text password sent from client to Spring Boot server with the password in Keycloak database to make sure they are the same before I let the user reset their password?

```
{
  "current_password": string,
  "password": string
}
```

At the moment I am only able to do a password reset without validation on the current password by

```
  userResource.resetPassword(credential);
```

Comment: Well, you could try to re-authenticate the user before trying to reset the password (assuming you're already doing that in your application - otherwise why not let the user reset the password directly via Keycloak's facilities?)

Comment: Currently rebuilding an application for a client and have to keep the functionality of a form with three fields `current password` `new password` `repeat new password`. I was thinking re-authenticating the user but we want to make it secure in a way that if I send the request in postman it should fail. So the validation needs to happen in one transaction

Comment: Does Keycloak's facilities have such a form that allows user to enter `current password` , right now I only see input for the new password.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that. However, I'd assume that Keycloak's account management pages should require entering the current password.